# I want to calculate average release in azure devops

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline, release-management

Is there a way to calculate the average number of days it takes to deploy code on production in azure DevOps? I want to calculate after how many days we deploy code on the production environment.

Comment: If you don't mind external tool, we are building Reliza Hub which does what you want among other things.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.